# Unexpected compiler exception EXCEPTION

Tags: rascal

I was wondering what this error meant while creating a case in a `visit` statement?[image]

This is an example of the case causing it:

`` case (Statement) `<Lifetime lt>: <Statement stmt>` => (Statement) `<Statement stmt>` ``

My goal with this is just to delete the `Lifetime` statement together with the following colon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this and many apologies for this brutal and incomprehensible message. The error means that there is a parse error in one of the concrete fragments between ` and `.

We will improve the reporting of this kind of errors!

Comment: I see. Thank you for the answer and I'll just have to make my cases more specific to make this work.